# How do you test if a PCI slot is working - motherboard diagnostic software?

Tags: pci-express

I suspect that my motherboard is bad, and that my PCI-E slot is not working.

I have a Gigabyte motherboard that had a Hauppage 2250 working fine in the PCI-E slot for many months.

However - recently - would not get TV channels that I used to get --- until finally Media center cant detect any channels at all.  Got a new tuner card (ATI 350 card) - cant detect any channels.  The cable signal is good - I have it connected directly to a TV - all channels come in clear.

SO that is why I suspect a motherboard problem.  Are there any motherboard diagnostic scanner utilities that can verify I need a new motherboard>

Comment: As this only indirectly answers your question, I'm throwing it up as a comment.  Are you using an antenna with the tuners?  If so, the transition to digital broadcasting could be the culprit.  Some newer TVs are equipped with converters built-in, but TV tuners such as the Hauppage 2250 may not be equipped to automatically convert the analog broadcasts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to troubleshoot a slot is with need another, known-good slot, preferably on another motherboard.  Place the card in another slot, and if it works there, the first slot is bad.  If it doesn't work in the known-good motherboard, it's probably a bad card.

If you have multiple cards and multiple slots on the same motherboard, trying the cards in different slots might help.  Remove all cards but the one you're trying to troubleshoot, and try it in different slots in turn.  Again, if it works in some slots but not in others, the card is fine, and the trouble is on the motherboard.  This isn't as certain as using another motherboard to test, but can be useful if you don't have spare parts lying around.